# Display first 500 characters with Twig in tinypress

Tags: github, twig

How can I display the first 500 characters of my posts in github hosted sites' `index.html` file ?
I've tried this, as seen in [Twig docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) :

```
 {{ post.content | slice(0,500) }} <a href="{{ post.url }}">Read more ...</a>
```

But it doesn't work. It just displayed the `<a></a>` tag.

Comment: *It just displayed the tag* An HTML tag? A Twig tag? Please describe it more precisely.

Comment: Do GitHub hosted sites and/or Tinypress support Twig templates?